# Pure CSS alter selection

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have a 3 section page. Each `div` ( section ) has it's own unique `ID` which has two forms of nav: arrows and buttons ( Which share the same `id's` and jQuery ). When you are on a particular section, the url changes to the name of the id associated w/ the `div`. Pretty standard.

```
<div class="nav-buttons-wrap">
    <a href="#Welcome" class="nav-buttons"></a>
    <a href="#We-Are-The-Leader" class="nav-buttons"></a>
    <a href="#Services" class="nav-buttons"></a>
</div>

<a href="#We-Are-The-Leader" class="down">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>

<!-- SECTION 1 --> <div id="#Welcome"></div>
<!-- SECTION 2 --> <div id="#We-Are-The-Leader"></div>
<!-- SECTION 3 --> <div id="#Services"></div>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

            var navBarHeight = 0; // change if nav bar height changes
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': ($target.offset().top - navBarHeight)
            }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuint', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is working just fine, but now I want the `.nav-buttons` to change color according to the `ID` in the url, in other words, if you are on the section associated w/ specific `ID`. So if you are on SECTION 2, the second button is a different color than the other two.

I'm not good enough at jQuery to figure out a clean way to add a class to the 'selected' button and know that is one option so I am open to that kind of solution but ideally I would love to know if there is a pure `CSS` way to do this. I could not find one.

Comment: add an active class to the link/button just clicked on... (i.e. after `e.preventDefault()` add something like `this.addClass('active');` and then add a CSS style to make the `.active` elements look the way you want

Comment: @ochi Adding a class to the link clicked on works for what I want, but more importantly, it needs to be when the user is on the page section associated w/ id and they got there other ways than clicking on button. Clicking button is an afterthought...

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish this is to listen to the `hashchange` event on `window`.  Checkout this [working example on Plunker](http://run.plnkr.co/9BGyK5OZaNq6Gw59/).  [The code can also be found on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQrUz5Ot6IUnlOkrtBuG?p=preview).

The key part is this:

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
  $(".nav-buttons-wrap a").removeClass("selected");
  $(".nav-buttons-wrap a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: this works BUT it only works on hash change which is a problem, because you can scroll the page without changing the hash in the url. The button needs to change color when it's on specific section...

Comment: @user2684452 have a look at `scrollspy.js` (http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollSpy/)